# Calculate average of column from MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sum, average

I've got a table that I am trying to calculate the average of the values in a column.  Here is my lookup:

```
SELECT SUM(P1_Score) AS value_sum FROM tblMatches Where P1_ID LIKE $playerID
```

Any idea how I can determine the average (sum of values / total rows)?

Comment: Oddly enough, there's an analytic called: AVG that does just that :D [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: FYI - You should be using PDO, and not exposing your MySQL queries to raw variables.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use [AVG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) like so:

```
SELECT AVG(P1_Score)
```

Comment: Thanks...its actually a statistics page where filter for a player and view the results of the matches.

So I would want to show both the total number of games and average number of games per match.

Comment: @DoubleA: perform different queries then. They have nothing in common

Comment: Sounds like in the case where you need the total and average for the same set, you might want to use `SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(P1_Score)`, from which you could pull out the sum/total and derive the average. With frameworks like Rails where you can only send one query at a time to your database, assuming your database is on another server, that combined query would save you one round trip.

Comment: he doesn't need two queries just `SELECT SUM(P1_Score), AVG(P1_SCORE) ...`

Comment: @Michael thanks for clarification, I did not mean they need 2 queries though

Answer (score 9):

So in your case:

```
$gameswon = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(P1_Score) AS value_sum 
                         FROM tblMatches 
                         WHERE P1_ID LIKE '".$playerid."'");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using AVG() aggregate function instead of SUM

```
$gameswon = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(P1_Score) AS value_sum FROM tblMatches Where P1_ID LIKE '".$playerid."' . "GROUP BY XXXX");
```

and XXXX is the column that you want to get average for such as player